# javascript replace() not working with 3 dots

Tags: javascript, replace

I have a string eg.

```
what a nice pony...and also nice dog...and nice car.
```

I want to replace each instance of `'...'` with `'&#8203;...&#8203;'`
This works for the first `'...'` with the following:

```
var updatedStr =  str.replace('...', "&#8203;...&#8203;");
```

But I want all instances of '...' updated and have tried:

```
var updatedStr =  str.replace(/.../g, "&#8203;...&#8203;");
```

but this updates the whole string with dots.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: string may have a replaceAll method - in modern browsers - something to think about and easy to polyfill for microsofts attempts at creating a browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the dots and make the regex global:

```
var updatedStr = str.replace(/\.\.\./g, '&#8203;');
```

Answer (score 1):

The first example works because you’re just doing normal string replacement, but in the second example, you’re using a regular expression.

When you use a `.` in a regular expression, this is actually a special character that says “match any character you can find”.

If you want to literally match three dots/periods, you need to “escape” them in the regular expression by using a backslash before each. The backslash in a regular expression disables the special functionality of the period.

```js
str.replace(/\.\.\./g, "&#8203;...&#8203;");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one! :D

```js
const str = "what a nice pony...and also nice dog...and nice car."
const updated = str.split('...').join('&#8203;...&#8203;')

console.log(updated)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a square brackets with the count of the dots and use a global regex to replace all occurrences of `...`.

The special characters mostly lose their meaning inside square brackets. The reason the dot `.` was not working is that it has a special meaning: It matches any character (except for line terminators) unless it is escaped:

```js
var str = "what a nice pony...and also nice dog...and nice car.";
var updatedStr =  str.replace(/[.]{3}/g, "&#8203;...&#8203;");
console.log(updatedStr);
```